# How do I write a sparql insert with reification?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I pulled this example right from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671227/what-does-reify-and-reification-mean-in-relation-to-rdf).

Given this statement how should the sparql insert query be written?

```
GEORGE SAYS-THAT 'ROVER IS-A DOG'
STMTID  IS-A STATEMENT
STMTID  HAS-SUBJECT ROVER
STMTID  HAS-PREDICATE IS-A
STMTID  HAS-OBJECT DOG
GEORGE  SAYS-THAT STMTID
```

I am completely lost as to how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, you're just looking for a concrete **insert** command that would create those triples for you. You could use:

```
prefix ex: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845314/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

insert data { 
  ex:George ex:says [ a rdf:Statement ;
                      rdf:subject ex:Rover ;
                      rdf:predicate rdf:type ;
                      rdf:object ex:Dog ]
}
```